# iframe loading indication on IE

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe

I have a page with an iframe.
When the user clicks on a link and navigate inside the iframe there is no native loading indication on IE (there is on other browsers) so it is not clear to the user that the page is loading.

Is it possible to trigger native loading indication on IE with some action in the top frame?
Something like making a dummy ajax request or similar.

Thank

Comment: Does anybody have an answer to this question?